# Loading different views for different profiles

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm not sure I understand how to use profile views within a Sencha Touch 2 app.

```
Ext.define(App.view.phone.PhonePanel, {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'Compare'
    config: {
         items: [
            { xtype: 'PanelA' },
            { xtype: 'Panel B' }
         ]
    }
})

Ext.define(App.view.tablet.TabletPanel, {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'Compare'
    config: {
         layout: 'vbox',
         items: [
            { xtype: 'PanelA', flex: 1 },
            { xtype: 'Panel B', flex: 1 }
         ]
    }
})
```

And then within the Phone Profile, it adds "PhonePanel" as a view, and the Tablet profile adds "TabletPanel"; and then when that specific profile is loaded it only loads those additional views.

The problem I'm having is that Sencha is loading files from both profiles, and doing

```
this.getAview().push({xtype:'Compare'});
```

While the phone profile is active, it actually pushes the Tablet's version of the xtype. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

These are the different steps to create profiles in a Sencha Touch 2 application :

**Create app/profile/Base.js containing the following code**

You're more likely to need a base profile if you execute the same code at the launch of the app for both the profiles. So this step is mandatory

```
Ext.define('App.profile.Base', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Profile',

  launch: function () {

    /* Custom Code */

    Ext.fly('booting').destroy();
  }

});
```

**Create app/profile/Phone.js containing the following code**

If you chose to go without the base controller, then be sure to extend `Ext.app.Profile` instead of `App.profile.Base` :

```
Ext.define('App.profile.Phone', {
  extend: 'App.profile.Base',

  config: {
    controllers: ['Main'],
    views: ['Main']
  },

  isActive: function() {
    return Ext.os.is.Phone;
  },

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('App.view.phone.Main');
    this.callParent();
  }
});
```

**Create app/profile/Tablet.js containing the following code**

If you chose to go without the base controller, then be sure to extend `Ext.app.Profile` instead of `App.profile.Base` :

```
Ext.define('App.profile.Tablet', {
  extend: 'App.profile.Base',

  config: {
    controllers: ['Main'],
    views: ['Main']
  },

  isActive: function() {
    return Ext.os.is.Tablet || Ext.os.is.Desktop;
  },

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('App.view.tablet.Main');
    this.callParent();
  }
});
```

**Create app/view/phone/Main.js containing the following code**

```
Ext.define('App.view.phone.Main', {

  extend: 'Ext.Container',

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [{
      html:'This is the main view for the phone profile'
    }]
  }
});
```

**Create app/view/tablet/Main.js containing the following code**

```
Ext.define('App.view.tablet.Main', {

  extend: 'Ext.Container',

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [{
      html:'This is the main view for the tablet profile'
    }]
  }
});
```

That's it. You should be all set.

Hope this helped

Comment: thanks for formatting my answer.. i didn't know you could do that to other peoples posts

Comment: Yes you can, just click the 'edit' link below a post if you think its format is not at its best. As you don't have 2000 reputation yet, you edit will be reviewed by other users (with more than 2000 reputation) and be validated or rejected. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: My problem is echoed here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197910-Problem-with-Sencha-Profiles

And in specific, the problem I have is that when I load 'Panel A', its getting added to the tablet view and not the phone view.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same xtype twice.

Think of an xtype as a short name for your component. Each component needs to have a unique shortname or it will just get overwritten  by the more recent definition.

Change the above two components to something like `xtype: 'tabletcompare'` and `xtype: 'phonecompare'`.

AND

```
this.getAview().push({xtype:'tabletcompare'}) <br>
```

Or

```
this.getAview().push({xtype:'phonecompare'})
```

when referencing the objects.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Helps, but raises more questions. I was under the impression that using profiles was a way to limit the number of files loaded (but it still loads tablet view files when a phone profile is active).

My goal was to be able to share navigation and controllers, but load only the views appropriate for the device.

Even with an if statement checking every push(), I ran into the problem of it loading Panel1 and Panel2 only into the TabletPanel.

Comment: Glad it helps. The multi resolution environment can be handled several ways. One way is: make a standard prefix for the two environments and hold the used one in a global variable. So at runtime you detect tablet or phone based on the resolution and then store a variable like this.resolution = 'phone'; then when ever you are calling a view to be rendered then you you can do this this.getAview().push({xtype: resolution + 'compare'}); Downsides to this approach are that you would need to programmatically call the rendering of each view element which can be inefficient or near impossible.

Comment: I tend to use separate folders and files to house my main view scaffolds but then use shared custom elements within them that have inherited layouts. I'm not sure what would be best for your project.

Comment: sencha offers a profile functionality which is what you are referring too i think but it needs to be setup in the app.js file and subsequently the profiles that dictate which gets used. All of this code phone and tablet gets minified and added to the app so 6 one way half dozen the other.