# Sencha Touch profiles - how to use when instantiating views

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently have 2 profiles: Tablet and Phone.
Each profile loads in a different view like so:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.tablet.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.loginview',
    ...
}
```

However in the app bootstrap code, I have these lines:

```
 var loginView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Login')
 Ext.Viewport.add(loginView);
```

This won't work as my views are now split by profile.  How do I now request the login view which has been loaded by the profile?  I don't want to do this:

```
 var loginView = Ext.is.os.Phone? Ext.create('MyApp.view.phone.Login') : Ext.create('MyApp.view.tablet.Login')
```

as I thought that was the whole point of having profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you should detect a profile.

Take a look at my answer here : [Loading different views for different profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499431/loading-different-views-for-different-profiles/13500602#13500602)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok thanks, so instead of adding the view to the viewport in the app.js I would do it in the profile?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define all views that are relying upon the active profile in your profile files. 
A typical simple profile looks like:

```
Ext.define('yourapp.profile.Phone', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Profile',
    config: {
        name: 'Phone',
        controllers: ['YourController'],
        views: ['Login'] // the MyApp.view.phone.Login view will be used if Phone profile is active
    },
    isActive: function() {
        return Ext.os.is('Phone');
    }
}
```