# Responsive Layout in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am building a cross platform Application using Sencha Touch. The application is for both mobiles and tablets.
The MainPage of the application contains a list and a form. Now I want that when the device is tablet, the list should appear in the left side of the device in 1/3rd of the screen width. and the form should appear in the remaining page. But when the device is mobile, entire screen should be filled with form only and I need to provide a button at the top of the page, clicking on which will open up the list. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Sencha Touch [Profiles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Profile)

If you are looking for a lovely explanation of how this could be implemented check => [Loading different views for different profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499431/loading-different-views-for-different-profiles/13500602#13500602)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by checking the condition in initialize function on main page. And you can write your code by checking condition whether it is tablet or not.